# Sending Email using Gmail Api in dot net with Multiple gmail accounts and without using SMTP link, without port

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, gmail-api

I am looking for an example code or tutorial for sending Email through **Gmail API**.

User is able to provide his gmail credentials and authorizing my app to access his compose email option.

But from that point I don't know how to send email.

I have got the messages and all the details but do not know how to link those with my project currently and for future use.

**Please read this before posting anything.**

Please note that using the gmail Host, smtp, port and working with less secure api is not required. As I am already using this for sending the email from single email address. I need the sample code which is using **Gmail API** to send the email of the account holder after authorizing the application.

*Note:* This is not related to the simple codinging which are linked with *smtp,http, post.*

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: You can find a lot of answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: Share the use of api not smtp or port, etc in these examples @akac ... I am asking the question about the use of gmail Api and use of multiple accounts in single application with the help of different account holders in the website.